# TV show where a man receives a message that he can't decipher which turns out to be a picture of the alien

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I remember a black-and-white television show a long time ago where a man received a message from an alien and he could not decipher it.  It turned out that it was not a message but rather a digital picture of what the alien looked like.

Can anyone help me identify the name of the TV show and the name of the episode?

Comment: In some ways, this reminds me of "Music of the Spheres" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_the_Spheres_(The_Outer_Limits)) from The Other Limits, but there, the transmission is a more literal image of the alien, transforming those who hear it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you describe this could feasibly be *A for Andromeda*. Black and white series from 1961 that features the decoding of a digital alien message. Have never watched it in full so cannot say if there is a scene where the message renders an image of the alien. You can view the series on YouTube.

Comment: good point! will do that!

Answer (score 2):

FYI The 1995 season of *The Outer Limits* featured an episode called "The Message" which except for the fact it is in colour contains a premise and scene very much as you describe. You can see a still from the episode showing the drawing, decoded from binary notation on [this web page](https://genresnaps.com/outer-limits-the-message-s1e17/).

[image: Still from the episode showing the drawing of the alien alongside a human]

Initially I posted this as part of one answer but it was suggested that I split my answer in two so that if one of these is what you are looking for you can easily mark it as correct.